# MyPy not considering dataclass attribute mechanics

Tags: python-3.x, type-hinting, mypy, python-dataclasses

I am developing a Python3.8 project with usage of `typing` and `dataclasses`, and automatic tests include `mypy`. This brings me in a strange behavior that I do not really understand...

In short: **Mypy seems not to understand `dataclass` attributes mechanics that, to my understanding, make them instance attributes.**

Here's a minimal example, with a package and two modules:

- `__init__.py`: void
- `app_events.py`:

```py
class AppEvent:
    pass
```

- `main.py`:

```py
import dataclasses
import typing

from . import app_events


class B:
    """Class with *app_events* as instance attribute."""
    def __init__(self):
        self.app_events: typing.List[app_events.AppEvent] = []

    def bar(self) -> app_events.AppEvent:
        # no mypy complaint here: the import is correctly distinguished
        # from the attribute
        ...


class C:
    """Class with *app_events* as class attribute."""
    app_events: List[app_events.AppEvent]

    def chew(self) -> app_events.AppEvent:
        # mypy considers app_events to be the class attribute
        ...

@dataclasses.dataclass
class D:
    app_events: typing.List[app_events.AppEvent] = \
        dataclasses.field(default_factory=list)

    def doo(self) -> app_events.AppEvent:
        # same here: mypy considers app_events to be the class attribute
        ...
```

And the typecheck result:

- PyCharm complains, for methods `C.chew` and `D.doo`: `Unresolved attribute reference 'AppEvent' for class 'list'`
- `mypy` complains, still for methods `C.chew` and `D.doo`, that `error: Name 'app_events.AppEvent' is not defined`.

No issue for `B.bar` as written, though if `app_events` attribute is declared as a class attribute (instead of being defined in `self.__init__`, then `mypy` raise the same complaint.)

**-> any idea how to understand/solve/circumvent this elegantly?**

I'd really like not to rename my module and attributes, but if you have nice names in mind, please do not hesitate to propose :-)

Comment: Maybe import the class directly: `from .app_events import AppEvent`. This can also be done for all the `typing` and `dataclasses` import.

Comment: mmh, nice idea! Even if it does not really fit my usage, due to multiple import from this module, plus an additional, unwanted import loop. I may find my way by solving the latter first though :-)